# How to create an irregular shaped imagebutton where transparent part of image is not clickable?

Tags: android, touch, transparent, imagebutton, clickable

I have an irregular shaped PNG image for example a round image where the corners are transparent.

How can I create an imagebutton of this image and not letting the corners being touchable?

If possible I may want to create other irregular shaped imagebuttons.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the second answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778279/android-creating-shaped-button), I believe it's exactly what you need.

Later edit:

Quick summary:

1. Use a `TouchListener` instead of `ClickListener`
2. Inside the listener, if the event is `MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN`, get the touch coordinates
3. Check the image's pixel at the coordinates you obtained earlier; if the pixel is not transparent, consider the button was clicked, otherwise ignore the event.

Comment: By changing the "hot zone" or "clickable area" method? Let me try and see. Thanks mate.

Comment: Elaborate on this, please. "Couldn't get it work" could mean anything. The answer I pointed you to seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: Sorry still new in Android, I'm not exactly sure how to use that snippet into my code. Currently I have an ImageButton listening an onClickEvent. How does that onTouch or MotionEvent fill in?

Comment: Yes I'm able to get the touched coordinates. How do I check whether the coordinates are belonged to which image? And how do I check the transparency using the pixel? The getPixels() method is for Bitmap. Perhaps I need to draw the buttons using Bitmap?

Comment: Get the bitmap by using `Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.YOUR_IMAGE_ID);`. Now you have the bitmap object and you can use `getPixel` to check for transparency.

Comment: Using Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.id.myimageid); I get a null point exception for getPixel

Comment: If using Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.myimagename); I get java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Comment: Now I'm able to getPixel from the image. My image is a round shaped image with corners of the image being transparent. But I'm still getting a touch event on the corners(transparent) part of the image.

Comment: If the pixel is non-transparent it means the touch is valid; you have to do your processing here and return `true`.

Comment: Yes I got it working with another image below it! Thanks a lot Gabriel :)