# How can I make Android View position and size be shown always with the same proportion on any screen size?

Tags: android, android-layout

I've tried position the button with this layout parameters:

```
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Butt1"
    android:id="@+id/b1"
    android:rotation="-9"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="205dp"
```

My idea is to make the button transparent later and keep the visual hint of the background image to let the user know there is a button there.

I've already made it work on my device by manually positioning and sizing the button, on my device using margin top 205dp I get this:

[image: This is the result on my device]

On another device the buttons are not aligned / sized as the background image:

[image: This is on another device]

Any idea on how I can match position and size of the button on any device?

Comment: I suggest you improve your question by showing all the layout, an image of what you want to achieve and another showing the wrong result. -- as a side note, I can see from your question your Android knowledge is newbie and I probably can also guess what the problem is. But the fact is that the effort to reply a question that is not well written is more then what I'm willing to spend in helping a random stranger ;)

Comment: Posso risponderti in italiano? @DanieleSegato

Comment: Even if we are both Italian this website is not :) so please stick to English

Comment: @DanieleSegato ok no problem...i edited my own post with the screenshot of my device where i create the buttons and an other screenshot in an other device with different resolution...i want that the buttons will be autoresized and positioned correctly

Comment: I'm looking at your edited version, are you trying to put full screen background and "transparent" buttons on the area the background image has buttons?

Comment: @DanieleSegato yes it is my plan but for first i have to find a system to "auto-edit" the button resize and position for beacause only in my device will work correctly (if you see on the second screen you can see that the buttons are positioned down the image and have more widthed....how can i resolve?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105919/discussion-between-daniele-segato-and-mattia-romagnoli).

Comment: You should get the ratio position of shape on the Image like 0%, 30%,.Then you can caclulate  the position of it on any device.Because you know size of mobile , position of shape,you can get the posistion of it.

Comment: Edited question to match our chat (in italian) and provided an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [this](http://www.androidauthority.com/using-the-android-percent-support-library-630715/) library: it define version of the `RelativeLayout` with percent positioning / sizing ability.

I want to point out that using a transparent background and letting the button be hinted by the background image of your window is the "easy" way but is a bad practice. That way you give no visual feedback to the user touching your UI, you are forced to upload a big image with your App that will be stretched with inevitable artifacts and doesn't really well adapt to different screen aspect ratio.

You should try to build an UI where the button is an actual button, positioned in your screen.

In your case this isn't an easy task because you want irregular shaped buttons that overlap with each other (if you consider them rectangular). Thus you need to handle touch in a special /custom way.

If you decide to go with this other route check out this other questions and answers:

- [How to create an irregular shaped imagebutton where transparent part of image is not clickable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8224852/how-to-create-an-irregular-shaped-imagebutton-where-transparent-part-of-image-is)
- [Android: Creating shaped button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7778279/android-creating-shaped-button)

Another way can be to map the image with coordinates like you would do in HTML map tag. [This](https://github.com/catchthecows/AndroidImageMap) Android Library seems to implement that exact behavior in an Android Image Widget.

Comment: I think that the main problem is not that.
I think that he want a dynamic positioning of Buttons.
Example (Always at the center-Left of the screen).
But the problem is the background, he use it like an html page, but with phones it's different.
The best-easy way can be like my post? (i ask because you have a rep better than mine)
But he must use a ImageButton that have with background his own style of buttons.

Comment: he use an image as background, the image is stretched to match full screen, meaning if you work with percent over the screen size you'll always position the button at the right place. -- still a bad idea for other reasons :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a `<RelativeLayout>` and instead of `android:layout_marginTop="205dp"` use the property `android:layout_below` so you can specify the Button after who it is!

Example

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp" >
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/reminder" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/dates"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/times" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@id/times"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/name"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/times"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="@string/done" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The `Spinner` is after the `EdiText` and the `Button` is after the second `Spinner` ALWAYS

If you want always your button in the left-center of your screen try with this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:paddingLeft="16dp"
        android:paddingRight="16dp" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/play"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/score"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/play"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/times" />
            <Button
                android:id="@id/times"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/score"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/players"
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/times"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:text="@string/done" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Use a `LinearLayout` like a container and with the property of the `RelativeLayout` put it at the left(or right) and center-vertical so all the Buttons inside the `LinearLayout` change position from all screens dimension.

**Read the documents** that i post and see the **RelativeLayout paramenter** so you can find the solution that it's better for you.

**Italian:**
Credo tu sia italiano, se usi la proprietà `android:layout_below` dici praticamente che l'elemento con questa proprietà si deve posizionare subito sotto un determinato elemento specificato per `ID`
Poi se vuoi li spazi l'uno dall'altro con un `marginTop`.
Per mantenere il tutto centrato usa un LinearLayout, consideralo un container che ha come proprietà del `RelativeLayout` quelle di stare a sinistra e al centro della schermata, così si adatta ad ogni schermo.

Some [Relative Layout guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/relative.html)
And [parameters](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: Forse meglio se parlaimo inglese anche se siamo italiani (anche se il mio inglese lascia molto a desiderare....

so it can be helpful but if you see the screenshots, i can use this way for the margin from the 2nd to the 1st but how can i do with the margin top? If the resolution change the 1st pos change automatically if i gain the dp margin. And for the size of them?

Comment: I write with all two languages, i don't think it's a problem for the site!
And if you want the `Buttons` set all always at the center-right of the screen put them inside a `LinearLayout` with the paramenters `android:layout_centerVertical="true"` if you need the code i can write a little example

Comment: @MattiaRomagnoli post edited with some code for explain better what i say.
If you get some problem post all xml that you have so i can see and understand better your layout.xml