# Making an ImageButton - without button border nor highlight

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have two png-images for the pressed and released state of a button. I'd like to build a button that accomplishes the following:

1. Has no background/border (only those two images visible)
2. Does not highlight with a blue rectangle when clicked (only by cycling through those images)
3. Does not get activated, when the user clicks on a transparent part of the image.

[image: Red button with explamation mark, has the form of a stop sign]

As you can see, the button is not rectangular, so the last point mentioned above might be tricky.

I already tried to use an `ImageButton` and managed to meet point 1, but I failed at point 2.
Is there another `View` I can use, that does the work for me? If not, could you hint me what techniques I should look into to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `ImageView`

One image set as background, second as src. 
And it resolve all your problems

Comment: I used a selector to change the pressed state of the "button". That leaves only point 3, but it is not that important... Thank you for this suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

[Edit]
for third part- follow this https://stackoverflow.com/a/8086317/3811198
in short

Use a TouchListener instead of ClickListener

Inside the listener, if the event is MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, get the touch coordinates

Check the image's pixel at the coordinates you obtained earlier; if the pixel is not transparent, consider the button was clicked, otherwise ignore the event.

Comment: I tried using an `ImageButton` and adding the XML-attribute android:focusable="false". But when I click on the button, it still gets a blue highlight.

Comment: Awesome, that is exactly what I need, apparently. I will soon look further into this! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you use setBackground = "#0xxx"; on button in xml file the borders will desappear. Basically making it transparent using alpha

```
android:setBackground = "#0AAA"
```